# Display Google Search results over whole page

Tags: google-search

When I search using Google, the results page only takes up less than half of my screen. The longer titles are even cut of, such as:

```
Bla Bla long title about ...
```

even though the page has enough room to display the whole title.

Is there any way to display the Google results over the full width of my page?

I see the same effect on different browsers, so I don't think this is browser-specific.

Comment: No. Google does this for (I dunno) whatever reason. And there's no way to change this. Perhaps try a different search engine. I bet that even if you change some CSS to break out the text, it will still cap the titles short. Perhaps you can file in a support ticket with google so they hear about this bad designed behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the text using the developer tools, is it actually cutting/wrapping the text or is the response from Google received has the text cut/wrapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's search results will cut off all titles that are too long.  Based on some articles I've found (such as [this one](http://beantin.se/page-title-lengths-after-march-2014/)), Google allocates a little over 500 pixels for each title, which translates into approximately 57 characters (it may be a little more or less than that since Google uses a non-fixed-width font).

It is not possible to have the search results display really long titles without truncating them, because they are truncated by Google before being returned to the browser.  I verified this by doing a Google search with JavaScript and CSS disabled.

I found this [Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide](http://files.pxlpartner.ch.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/78746?CFID=09e8ae01-bce1-4ebf-bc0b-fda083aa3919&CFTOKEN=0) written by Google.  It includes tips for web developers on how to improve their web sites so that Google can more easily crawl, index, and understand their content.  On page 5, it describes how Google will only show a portion of long titles in the search results:

> **Use brief, but descriptive titles**
>
> Titles can be both short and informative. If the title is too long, Google will show only a portion of it in the search result.
>
> **Avoid**
>
> - using extremely lengthy titles that are unhelpful to users
> - stuffing unneeded keywords in your title tags

As you can see, Google wants to discourage web developers from using really long titles that may be unhelpful or difficult for users to read.  Google also wants to prevent web developers from spamming their titles with a bunch of keywords.  Truncating long titles helps Google achieve these goals.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on JavaScript in Safari under “Advanced” and your search will fill the page.

Comment: To improve your answer, it's best to elaborate a bit more on your solution, and attach some images of the process / result, to supply a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The F-Pattern.

Eye and cursor tracking research repeatedly showed that the user's view results in an F-shaped pattern. This was first discovered by Jakob Nielsen. Later on, experiments on google showed a triangle shape, which is related to the F pattern, as the most common pattern, as in this image below:

[image: F-pattern user interaction with website research]

Source: [How Do You Google? New Eye-Tracking Study Reveals Huge Changes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/roberthof/2015/03/03/how-do-you-google-new-eye-tracking-study-reveals-huge-changes/)

Keeping this basic format means making the user's search easier and more intuitive, as the access to relevant content is easier, and the content is thus easier to process for users. These are topics of UX design and usability. It's about the users' comfort.

If you look into the source link of the picture, you'll see that there are indications that this pattern may have changed to a straight downward line at the left side of the stream. Where changes come from, I don't know, probably an effect of mobile communication. However, also if this new pattern holds, the left part of the screen still receives the most attention. It's thus logical, from a UX viewpoint, to place the most relevant content on the left.

I do wonder if this effect is also due to the left -> right orientation of the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score -2):

My solution (crazy, I admit) is to search on my iPad. Here Google does display much wider titles, and you can do the search much more efficiently.